# How do I configure the the jackson objectmapper to correctly deserialize to pojo?

Tags: java, deserialization, jackson

I'm having a bit of a problem understanding how i should configure the objectMapper and pojo when deserializing. My Json is created by another application that
supports both xml and json. It returns a list with myobject, but the Json contains the type, like this:

```
[
    {
        "myobject": {
            "somethingcool": "amazing",
            "contactPersonsForMyObject": [
                "test.test@gmail.com",
                "test@test.se"
            ],
            "myObjectId": "c85e48730501bfae41e67714c6131b7d"
        }
    },
    {
        "myobject": {
            "somethingcool": "cool",
            "contactPersonsForMyObject": [
                "test.test2@gmail.com",
                "test@test2.se"
            ],
            "myObjectId": "c85e48730501bfae41e67714cqwerty"
        }
    }
]
```

My class:

```
public class MyObject {

    private String myObjectId;
    private String somethingcool;
    private List<String> contactPersonsForMyObject;

    public String getMyObjectId() {
        return myObjectId;
    }

    public void setMyObjectId(String myObjectId) {
        this.myObjectId = myObjectId;
    }

    public String getSomethingcool() {
        return somethingcool;
    }

    public void setSomethingcool(String somethingcool) {
        this.somethingcool = somethingcool;
    }

    public List<String> getContactPersonsForMyObject() {
        return contactPersonsForMyObject;
    }

    public void setContactPersonsForMyObject(List<String> contactPersonsForMyObject) {
        this.contactPersonsForMyObject = contactPersonsForMyObject;
    }
}
```

But when doing:

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = mapper.convertValue(rootNode, new TypeReference<List<MyObject>>() {});
```

I'm getting a exception stating:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized field "myobject" (Class com.domain.MyObject), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.domain.MyObject["myobject"])
```

It's like the mapper do not understand the extra "layer". 
When serializing to get this structure it is possible to configure the mapper like this: `mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);`

So there should be somehow to do the reverse?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is to use `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation on type (class), which will include additional type information. In your case it looks as if you wanted to include a type id as property key.

If so, inclusion method should be "as wrapper object", and you will also need to define what type id of "myobject" binds to -- this can be done by adding `@JsonTypeName("myobject")` for `MyObject` class (it needs to be included in subtype of whatever has `@JsonTypeInfo`, but in this case both would be added for the same class).

Comment: Please could you elaborate your answer, maybe be some code example? I find the documentation for this hard to understand.

Comment: You may want to ask this on jackson users list; also, googling can find decent articles (from fasterxml jackson wiki, cowtowncoder.com blog), if javadocs for @JsonTypeInfo are not clear enough.

Answer (score 4):

You need to give it concrete classes and not interfaces. So

```
List<Map<String, MyObject>> myObjects = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<ArrayList<HashMap<String, MyObject>>>() {
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your json has an extra level of nesting: you have a list of Maps of Strings to MyObjects, not a List of MyObjects.  You'd need to read it like this:

```
List<Map<String, MyObject>> myObjects = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, MyObject>>>() {
        });
```

Or else change whatever is generating this json to ditch the inner Map (IMHO that'd be better).

Comment: 1. Yes I know, your example is like implementing a wrapper. This is not what I want to do.

Comment: 2. I can't ditch the inner map since I do not have power over the application

Answer (score 2):

Change `List<String>` to `ArrayList<String>`
and then

```
MyObject myObject = mapper.readValue(json, MyObject.class);
```

Add the following constructor to `MyObject` class

```
@JsonCreator
public MyObject(@JsonProperty("myObjectId") String myObjectId,
             @JsonProperty("somethingcool") String somthingcool,
             @JsonProperty("contact") ArrayList<String> contactPersonsForMyObject) {

   this.myObjectID = myObjectId;
   this.somethingcool = somethingcool;
   this.contactPersonsForMyObject = contactPersonsForMyObject;    
}
```

and change the return value for the getter to ArrayList